# Exponential integral problem

Tags: integration, exponential-function, exponentiation

I am trying to solve this

$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax^k-bx}dx$

I tried to solve this by considering this as an laplace transform of $e^{-ax^k}$
,but I cannot find it in a laplace table or in online laplace calculator.

Please give me some help, thanks!

Comment: I doubt this integral has any elegant closed form. The case $k=3$ requires Airy B-functions and hypergeometric functions, the case $k=4$ - generalised hypergeometric functions... Where does this problem come from?

Comment: this sort of question was asked here at several occassions

Comment: I am doing some research of analyzing the rate of wireless ad hoc network.Actually, k here is smaller than 1.Would it be solvable if k = 0.5?

Comment: yes for k= 0.5 it is sovable

Comment: it will give you a (derivative of a) error function...

Comment: thanks! I will try it out.

Comment: you are welcome! every other value of  $k$ will become quiet nasty i guess

Comment: I have tried to solve the k=0.5 case,and I found that this integral will turn out to be like $\int_{0}^{\infty} 2x e^{-ax^2+bx}dx$, which is not as the same as error function.any suggestion? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no closed form solution for the general case. We know this because, if such a solution were to have existed, humanity would not have been forced to invent [error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) and [Airy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function) functions in order to be able to express its value for the special cases $k=2$ and $k=3$, respectively $($assuming, of course, that *k* is an integer. If not, then we can also add $k=\dfrac12$ and $k=\dfrac13$ to the list, since, in this case, a simple substitution of the form $t=\sqrt x$ or $u=\sqrt[3]x$ reduces them to the previously mentioned two$)$ For other cases, $($ [generalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function) $)$ [hypergeometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) are inevitable. I am afraid that, in your case, numerical and asymptotic approaches are the only way forward. Also, the integral you mentioned in the comments, $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty xe^{-ax^2+bx}dx$, is expressible in terms of the *complementary error function* $($see the first link above$)$. For positive values of *a*, the result is $\dfrac1{2a}-\dfrac{\sqrt\pi}4\cdot\dfrac{b~e^{C^2}\text{erfc}(c)}{a\sqrt a}$ , where $c=\dfrac b{2\sqrt a}$ .

Comment: hi, maybe I should use hypergeometric series.but I am a little confused of how to convert this one to a hypergeometric series? Should I break the exponential term into two part and use taylor series? thanks!

Comment: @KennyYang: It definitely seems like a good start.